# SQL Server query. JOIN by latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

```
UnitInfo(UnitID, ...), 
UnitList(UnitID, ...) 
UnitMonitoring(RecordID,UnitID, EventDate, ...)
```

`UnitList` is a subset of `UnitInfo` (in terms of data and in terms of columns).  `UnitMonitoring` receives records time to time pertaining to `UnitList` (for every `UnitID` in `UnitMonitoring` we will have many records) filling `EventDate`.  (`UnitInfo` has extended info).

I can't figure how to build a query so that for every `UnitID` in `UnitList` I get `UnitMonitoring` record such that `EventDate` is the latest one.

So far I have

```
SELECT a.UnitID, a.Name, b.EventDate 
FROM UnitInfo a INNER JOIN UnitMonitoring b 
WHERE a.UnitID IN (SELECT UnitID FROM UnitList)
```

which yields all records from `UnitMonitoring`

Comment: Thanks guys.  I wonder which query would be almost independent in terms of time execution when UnitMonitoring fills up to 10^6 records.

Comment: only you know what the distribution of your records are likely to be when you reach 10^6 rows - would that by 10^5 rows for 10 units, 10 rows for 10^5 units, or something in between? If possible, I'd suggest that you try to populate your tables with test data that fits, and then try each solution. You'll probably want indexes that assist your queries at this point - possibly one on UnitID, EventDate

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?  (Knowing this determines which answer best firs you needs, so for now I'm voting for the most generic but optimal answer)

Comment: @Nickelodeon: this depend on how much records in `UnitMonitoring` do you have per unit (in average). If the number of records in `UnitList` (after applying all `WHERE` conditions) is `10%` or less of that in `UnitMonitoring`, then `OUTER APPLY` is more efficient, else `ROW_NUMBER` is.

Comment: Sql Server 2008 R2.  For now I assume uniform distribution for UnitID.  And I'll go reading about APPLY operator.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  ul.unitId, um.*
FROM    UnitList ul
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    UnitMonitoring umi
        WHERE   umi.UnitID = ul.unitID
        ORDER BY
                EventDate DESC
        )
```

This will handle the duplicates correctly and will return all units (those with no records in `UnitMonitoring` will have `NULL` values in corresponding fields)

Comment: Hm, you seem to be the only one who tried to take care of the situation with no records in UnitMonitoring (this is what i just ran into).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Select M.* 
From UnitList L 
  Join UnitMonitoring M
    On M.UnitId = L.UnitId
Where M.EventDate = 
   (Select Max(EventDate) From UnitMonitoring 
    Where UnitId = M.UnitId)
```

If There are multiple records with the same UnitId and EventDate, then you can still use this technique, but you need to filter on a unique field,  say the PK field in UnitMonitoring in this case is named `PkId`.

```
Select M.* 
From UnitList L 
  Join UnitMonitoring M
    On M.UnitId = L.UnitId
Where M.PkId = 
   (Select Max(PkId) From UnitMonitoring iM
    Where UnitId = M.UnitId
        And EventDate = 
             (Select Max(EventDate) From UnitMonitoring 
              Where UnitId = M.UnitId))
```

Comment: Although all other answers are acceptable, especcially by Damien_The_Unbeliever (which I found very educational) and Quassnoi which seems very concise and to the point I accept this answer as a solution because it's simple and is easiy extended into a query for creating reports for a certain period of time.  But again, it's really hard to accept a single answer.  Thanks to you all, now I won't get fired)))

Comment: What if EventDate has dublicates?

Answer (score 2):

I chose to go with a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) (CTE) to apply a ranking function ([`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)):

```
;WITH NumberedMonitoring as (
     SELECT RecordID,UnitID, EventDate, ...
          ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY UnitID ORDER BY EventDate desc) rn
     FROM UnitMonitoring
)
SELECT * FROM
    UnitList ul
        inner join
    NumberedMonitoring nm
        on
            ul.UnitID = nm.UnitID and nm.rn = 1
```

But there are many different solutions (the above could also be done using a subselect).

Common Table Expressions (quoting from above link):

> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary result set

That is, it lets you write a bit of the query first. In this case, I'm using it because I want to number the rows (using the ROW_NUMBER function). I'm telling it to restart the numbering for each UnitID (`PARTITION BY UnitID`), and within each unit ID, I want the rows numbered based on the EventDate descending (`ORDER BY EventDate desc`). This means that the row that receives row number 1 (within each UnitID partition) is the most recent row.

In the following select, I'm able to treat my CTE (`NumberedMonitoring`) as if it's any other table. So I'm just joining it to the UnitList table, and ensuring as part of the join conditions that I'm only selecting row number 1 (`rn = 1`)

Comment: So many new keywords for a newbie such as myself.  That is an educational, but I'm afraid to use it without understanding it.

Comment: @Nickolodeon - I've tried to add a bit more explanation, linked to another MSDN page.

Comment: Can I create a view from such a query?  B/c I'm afraid .NET Table Adapters designers won't accept it.

Comment: @Nickolodean - yes, you can create a view that uses CTEs - you just put this query where you'd normally put your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: That's what I did and now everything is working.  I'll use another query though where users specify date range (for reporting).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.UnitID, a.Name, MAX(b.EventDate) 
FROM UnitInfo a 
INNER JOIN UnitMonitoring b 
WHERE a.UnitID IN (SELECT UnitID FROM UnitList)
GROUP BY a.UnitID, a.Name
```